# MOSS 2007 - Customize Send To Menu

Tags: wss, sharepoint-2007

We currently have a need to add a custom menu item to the Send To menu within our document libraries that would allow a user to create a link to the currently selected list item within another library. When the user clicks on the new "Send Link to..." menu item, they should be prompted to browse to the library in which the link should be added. Once the user chooses a destination, the link, along with the metadata from the list item, should magically appear in the selected desitnation library. Once again, we only want a link, not a copy of the file. Is this possible to do? Code examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be in the send to menu? Can it also be directly in the context menu (say at the bottom)? If so, you can create a feature that deploys a CustomAction to the site. If it really, REALLY needs to be under the "send to" menu, you are going to have to use javascript (since that is how the out of the box context menu is created) to "hijack" the menu and insert your own item.

IMHO this is rarely needed, a CustomAction is the preferred way of doing this. It is the easiest and most "maintainable" (all it is is a feature + customaction definition with maybe some code, all of which are deployed using a solution).

More info on CustomActions **[here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/07/using-customaction-to-modify-system.html).**

P.S. if you do decide to go with javascript, don't go editing the out of the box sharepoint js files in SharePoint's 12 Hive, but add a ContentEditorWebPart to the page and insert your Javascript in there.

P.P.S. While assigning a method from an assembly as the action for a CustomAction is allowed in most cases, it is not for the ListEdit (item) context menu.

Answer (score 0):

What they say is that "Sharepoint server 2010 will have it out of the box", i.e. documents may stay where they were created and links go to the Records center (named "In Place Records Management, see http://www.cmswire.com/cms/document-management/the-scoop-sharepoint-2010-records-management-005948.php).
MOSS 2007 requires the actual document to be copied to the Records repository to be registered.